# Geometric Distribution in a 3 sided die?

Tags: probability, random-variables, bayes-theorem

Assume we have a 3 sided biased die. The probability that it lands on 1: $P(1) = \frac{2}{10} $. The probability that it lands on 2: $P(2) = \frac{3}{10}$, and $P(3) = \frac{5}{10}$.

Now we roll the die until we see the first 1. And Y is the number of total die tosses. Now I believe we can think of Y as a geometric random variable (please correct me if I am wrong).

The question is if Y=7, What is the expected number of 3's?

Now we know the 7th toss was a 1 so I believe we only need to check the first 6th tosses.
This is where I get a bit confused. We also know the first 6 tosses were not 1. So I only expect to see 2 or 3. Then I believe we only need to consider the possibility of getting 3's ***knowing*** that they were not 1. Am I correct? So we can do Bayes:

$$P(3 | \neq1) = \frac{P(3\ \& \neq 1) }{P(\neq1)} = \frac{P(3)}{P(\neq1)} = \frac{5/10}{8/10} = \frac{5}{8}$$
So the expected number of 3's become: $6$ tosses x 5/8 probability = 30/8 $\approx$ 3.75. So my assumption is the expected number of 3's is 3.75. Are my assumptions correct? I am confused about the first 6 tosses.

Comment: We roll a  $3$-sided die?

Comment: @Raffaele [They seem to exist as prisms which cannot settle on their ends](https://www.google.com/search?q=3-sided+die&source=lnms&tbm=isch) though a 6-sided die with numbers repeated may be easier. There is even a $2$-sided die with [curved sides](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cb/b3/37/cbb33791b0edfee5d3c2b0c6c5e93aef.jpg) though a coin may be easier

Comment: That is correct working.

Comment: $(7-1)\times \frac58 =3.75$ is correct

Comment: @Raffaele that's one of the beauties of working with pure maths... we don't care about the feasibility of creating a three-sided die with the desired probabilities, we can assume it's existence.  We could just as easily work with [spherical cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow) despite them not existing in real life.

Comment: @Henry Of course there exists a one face die https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CPw0HOoWUAAmjtr.jpg

Comment: @JMoriavitz That's why I love maths! A one sided die https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0057/6408/7896/articles/1-sided-dice-mobius_800x.jpg?v=1555640583